# What is the correct term for a "thesis statement" for individual body paragraphs?

Tags: terminology

Suppose a paper is organized with a thesis statement found in the introduction paragraph. Then, each body paragraph contains examples and details that support the thesis statement. The first sentence in each of those body paragraphs though acts as a "mini thesis statement".

Example:

> Cats make great pets. ← thesis statement
>
> - Cats improve human happiness. ← smaller sub-statement
> - Cats ward off pests.
> - Cats are easy to care for.

Each of the items starting with "-" above are the "mini thesis statements". They support one aspect of the thesis statement, but also serve to tell readers a summary of what to expect within the rest of the body paragraph.

What is a term for these?

Answer (score 9):

A [topic sentence](https://owl.purdue.edu/engagement/ged_preparation/part_1_lessons_1_4/index.html) would be the "thesis statement" of each paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call them arguments. A thesis is normally backed up by them.